# Why does C++ prints unsigned char value as negative?

Tags: c++, char, unsigned, type-promotion

I'm trying to understand the implicit conversion rules in C++ and I understood that when there are one operation between two primary types the "lower type" is promoted to the "higher type", so let say for:

```
int a = 5;
float b = 0.5;

std::cout << a + b << "\n";
```

should print 5.5 because 'a' gets promoted to float type. I also understood that unsigned types are "higher types" than the signed counter parts so:

```
int c = 5;
unsigned int d = 10;

std::cout << c - d << "\n";
```

prints 4294967291 because 'c' gets promoted to a unsigned int and since unsigned types wraps around when less than zero we get that big number.

However for the following case I don't understand why I am getting -105 instead of a positive number.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char a = 150;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(a - static_cast<unsigned char>(255)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I guess that this code:

```
a - static_cast<unsigned char>(255)
```

should result in a positive number so the final cast (to int) shouldn't affect the final result right?

Comment: You're forgetting about the integer promotions (all integer types smaller than `int`, which includes char, are promoted to `int` before we get to the rule that you describe at the start of your post)

Comment: This is C++. You should remove the `C` tag.

Comment: You guess that `a - static_cast<unsigned char>(255)` is positive but never bother to test it. You should have.

Comment: @Mark Benningfield Removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from `C++14`, chapter § 5.7

> The additive operators `+` and `-` group left-to-right. The usual arithmetic conversions are performed for
>   operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.

and for *usual arithmetic conversions*, (specific for this case)

> ....
>
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands

and, finally, for *integral promotions*, chapter § 4.5

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned
>   int.`

Hence, the `unsigned char` operands are promoted to `int` and then , the result is calculated.

Comment: The idea that is behind this rule, which I find quite useful to memorize it, is that integral types smaller than `int` are treated mostly as "storage types", i.e. as a way to save space in memory. When they are read back in registers to perform operations on them, they are naturally promoted to the machine register size (which usually coincides with `int`) and operations are performed accordingly.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, Indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried my code again with char16_t but it also results in a negative number, shouldn't this type be an exception to this implicit conversion?

Comment: @RandomGuy well, no. There's more broader scope for those types, but they also get promoted, nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the (implicit) conversion from `unsigned char` to `int` that happens to perform the `-` (subtract) operation.  This integer promotion happens any time you try to apply any integer operation to a value of some integral type smaller than `int`.

Comment: "to a value of some integral type smaller than int" well, excluding `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t`, is not it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, no exceptions for specific types.  Of course, some of those types might not be smaller than `int` on some platforms, so on those platforms, no conversion would apply.

Comment: Thanks! I din't know about this implicit conversion! Btw "...to apply any integer operation to a value of some integral type smaller than int." so this means it also applies to multiplication (\*) and division (/) operators or just sum (+) and subtraction (-)? I've tried multiplication (\*) and seems that the implicit cast doesn't happen.

Comment: @SouravGhosh to expand Chris' comment, the promotions for those types are specified by other rules in the same section from where you copied into your answer the rule which excludes those types.

Comment: @user2079303 right, only that does not limit them to be `int` or `unsigned int`. Anyways, it's true what Chris said in comments.

Comment: @SouravGhosh to maintain the pedantry: That's true to other types than `bool` which is promoted to exactly `int`.

Answer (score 2):

There are answers here showing what is happening. I won't repeat. I am going to give you a simple tool to help you.

Here is a trick you can do to **quickly** find the type of an expression:

```
template <class> struct Name; // purposely no definition given

Name<decltype(your_expression)> n;
```

This will generate a compiler error for undefined template 'Name', but what we are really interested in is the type of the template argument which will appear in the error message.

E.g. if you want to see what type you get when you do arithmetic between two `unsigned char`:

```
#include <utility>
template <class> struct Name;

auto test()
{
    Name<decltype(std::declval<unsigned char>() - std::declval<unsigned char>())> n;

   // or
   unsigned char a{};
   Name<decltype(a - a)> n2;
}
```

will get you

> ```
> error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Name<int>'
> ```

which will show you that the type of the expression is `int`

Of course this won't tell you the rules involved, but it is a quick starting point to see the type of the expression or to verify your assumption of the type of the expression.

Comment: Thanks! This helps! Working nice in visual studio 2013 compiler and gcc (mingw).